# How to call same parsing spider on next page - Scrapy Python

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, response

I'm trying to scrapying this page:
https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20151012004431AAyDFwK

I do it well, but now i need to go on the next page and do the same thing, referenced by the link "Next>" on the right top of the page.

I use this code in order to take the link from xpath and call the parse method.

```
    next_page = hxs.xpath('((//a[contains(@class,"Clr-b")])[3])/@href').extract()
    composed_string = "https://answers.yahoo.com" + next_page[0]
    URL = response.urljoin(composed_string)
    print("NEXT ->" + composed_string)
    yield scrapy.Request(URL, callback=self.parse_page)
```

EDIT: Full function http://pastebin.com/sCF2Atif

Comment: if parse_page is the function shown in the code provide, you're doing the right thing (calling the same function). Provide some additional information if I'm wrong

Comment: I edit the post with full function @RoshanJossey